# How to show $0\in [f(x), -y_0]\Leftrightarrow f(x)=y_0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Let $f: X\rightarrow S^n$ a continuous map defined on a topological space $X$ with values on the unit sphere $S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ endowed with the induced topology.

Let $y_0\in S^n$. How to show that

$$0\in [f(x), -y_0]\Leftrightarrow f(x)=y_0$$

where $[f(x), -y_0]=\{(1-t)f(x)-ty_0: t\in [0, 1]\}$ is the straight line connecting $f(x)$ and $-y_0$?

This is very clear when we draw a picture of segments connecting $y_0$ to $-y_0$ and $-y_0$ to $f(x)$ but I wasn't able toshow this properly.

Thanks.

P.s.: This is used to show that every continuous map $f: X\rightarrow S^n$ which is not surjective is homotopic to a constant map. As a matter of fact, if $f$ is not surjective we take $y_0\in S^n\setminus f(X)$ and we define

$$H(x, t)=\frac{(1-t)f(x)-ty_0}{|(1-t)f(x)-ty_0|},$$
and we have an homotopy, as long as we ensure $0\not\in [f(x), -y_0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $0=(1-t_0)f(x)-t_0y_0$ for some $t_0\in [0,1]$ implies $$(1-t_0)f(x)=t_0y_0\implies (1-t_0)||f(x)||=t_0||y_0||\implies (1-t_0)\cdot 1=t_0\cdot 1$$$$\implies t_0=\frac{1}{2}\implies 0=\left (1-\frac{1}{2}\right)f(x)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)y_0\implies f(x)=y_0.$$ Here, $\Bbb S^n=\{x\in\Bbb R^{n+1}:||x||=1\}$